# Exception while trying to load openNLP POS models

Tags: java, opennlp

I have been trying to use POS Models for POS tagging, but while loading the Models I get the following exception, and this happens for both maxent as well as perceptron models:

```
java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readLong(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.readDouble(Unknown Source)
at opennlp.model.BinaryFileDataReader.readDouble(BinaryFileDataReader.java:53)
at opennlp.model.AbstractModelReader.readDouble(AbstractModelReader.java:75)
at opennlp.model.AbstractModelReader.getParameters(AbstractModelReader.java:146)
at opennlp.perceptron.PerceptronModelReader.constructModel(PerceptronModelReader.java:69)
at opennlp.model.GenericModelReader.constructModel(GenericModelReader.java:59)
at opennlp.model.AbstractModelReader.getModel(AbstractModelReader.java:87)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.GenericModelSerializer.create(GenericModelSerializer.java:35)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.GenericModelSerializer.create(GenericModelSerializer.java:31)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:231)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.(BaseModel.java:190)
at opennlp.tools.postag.POSModel.(POSModel.java:86)
at nlpcheck.NlpPOC.POSTag(NlpPOC.java:54)
at nlpcheck.NlpPOC.main(NlpPOC.java:86)
```

I have tried loading the tokenizaton model (en-token.bin) and Its loading and working fine.
Following is java snippet that I am using to load Model:

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(MODEL_PATH);
POSModel model = new POSModel(is);
```

I have downloaded the models (en-pos-perceptron.bin, en-pos-maxent.bin) from http://www.opennlp.org/models-1.5/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the model file hosted on site mentioned above were corrupt, I was trying a different tool namely GATE(General architecture for Text Engineering) which was using the same model files so I copied them and put them on build path and it worked.